# boost::spirit::qi - whats wrong with this hex parse?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

Consider following code:

```
{
        std::string input = "FFFFFFF";
        int result = 0;
        auto itBeg = input.cbegin();
        auto itEnd = input.cend();
        if(!bsq::parse(itBeg, itEnd, bsq::int_parser<int, 16>(), result) || itBeg != itEnd)
        {
            throw std::exception();
        }
        std::cout << input << " means " << result << std::endl;
    }
    {
        std::string input = "FFFFFFFF";
        int result = 0;
        auto itBeg = input.cbegin();
        auto itEnd = input.cend();
        if(!bsq::parse(itBeg, itEnd, bsq::hex, result) || itBeg != itEnd)
        {
            throw std::exception();
        }
        std::cout << input << " means " << result << std::endl;
    }
    {
        std::string input = "FFFFFFFF";
        int result = 0;
        auto itBeg = input.cbegin();
        auto itEnd = input.cend();
        if(!bsq::parse(itBeg, itEnd, bsq::int_parser<int, 16>(), result) || itBeg != itEnd)
        {
            throw std::exception();
        }
        std::cout << input << " means " << result << std::endl;
    }
```

the first parse works fine on 0xFFFFFFF (note, 7 hex digits)
second one works ok on 0xFFFFFFFF (8 hex digits)
the third one fails and I cant understand why. isnt `int_parser<T, 16>` is essentially the same as bsq::hex?

Live on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca6ade7b996b6dee)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the third one fails and I cant understand why

You're using a signed parser, and hitting a type width boundary. Change it to:

```
bsq::uint_parser<unsigned int, 16>(), result)
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d8fbf5d5ddd8590))

---

> isnt `int_parser<T, 16>` is essentially the same as `bsq::hex`?

No.

[The documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/numeric/uint.html) says that `boost::spirit::qi::hex` will

> Parse an **unsigned integer** using *[..]* radix 16

Comment: what if I want to parse it to signed integer? I expect to get here -1

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg: Click on the link labelled "live demo".

Comment: and, by the way, just checked, bsq::parse(itBeg, itEnd, bsq::hex, result) fills the result with -1. being totally confused. the  bsq::uint_parser in your demo, the uint-ness of the parser belongs to uint-ness of input or result?

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg: I dunno tbh :)

Comment: Thanks! Will check with spirit mailing list, dont like to leave unanswered questions :)

Comment: The uint-ness of the parser "belongs" to the uintness of the parser. Full stop. The parser parses a uint. That you transform the attribute to signed later, that just invokes the standard transformation (in this case a simple `static_cast<>`. Nothing magical. It's exactly like [writing simple assignment in c++ `unsigned u = 0xFFFFFFFFF; int i = u;`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b1f4d8a5674fcd6) or even [`int i = 0xFFFFFFFF;`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42d141e3716beab6)

Comment: @sehe: Right but I guess he's asking why `0xFFFFFFFF` can't be interpreted as -1 and parsed by the `int_parser` in the first place. I'm guessing it's because we're talking values, not byte representations?